# TCP server on raspberry pi not connecting to android tcp client on raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, tcp, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, tcpserver

I am creating a TCP server on raspberry pi so that i can control it from my android phone over WIFI. I have connected both the pi and the phone to my WIFI router.

```
import socket
from cookieLED_FINAL import callLED

host = '192.168.100.100'
port = 5560

def setupServer():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Socket created.")
    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)
    print("Socket bind complete.")
    return s

def setupConnection():
    s.listen(1) # Allows one connection at a time.
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))
    return conn

def storeFile(filePath):
    picFile = open(filePath, 'wb')
    print("Opened the file.")
    pic = conn.recv(1024)
    while pic:
        print("Receiving picture still.")
        picFile.write(pic)
        pic = conn.recv(1024)
    picFile.close()

def dataTransfer(conn):
    # A big loop that sends/receives data until told not to.
    while True:
        # Receive the data
        data = conn.recv(1024) # receive the data
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        # Split the data such that you separate the command
        # from the rest of the data.
        dataMessage = data.split(' ', 1)
        command = dataMessage[0]
        if command == 'GET':
            reply = GET()
        elif command == 'REPEAT':
            reply = REPEAT(dataMessage)
        elif command == 'STORE':
            print("Store command received. Time to save a picture")
            storeFile(dataMessage[1])
            print("FINISHED STORING FILE")
            break
        elif command == 'LED_ON':
            callLED()
            reply = 'LED was on'
        elif command == 'EXIT':
            print("Our client has left us :(")
            break
        elif command == 'KILL':
            print("Our server is shutting down.")
            s.close()
            break
        else:
            reply = 'Unknown Command'
        # Send the reply back to the client
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
        print("Data has been sent!")
    conn.close()


s = setupServer()

while True:
    try:
        conn = setupConnection()
        dataTransfer(conn)
    except:
        break
```

When using IP:

192.168.100.100 :

> [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

127.162.100.100 or 0.0.0.0: The socket is being created but android client is not getting connected.

On my android phone i am using an app named TCP/UDP Test Tool which I downloaded from play store.

I am new on linux as well as on raspberry pi 3 B+.

OS: RASPBIAN

PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE: PYTHON 3.5

Comment: As you pointed out, the host should be `0.0.0.0`. `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address, aka `localhost`, which points to the computer itself (it may work).

Comment: What error message do you get (on your phone, or on the Pi if it detects the connection attempt)? Also, have you checked your firewall policies (`sudo iptables -L`)? These may prevent your Pi from accepting incoming connections.

Comment: No I haven't checked the firewall policies as I am new to linux so I don't know much about it. If you can please send me a link or something about checking the firewall on raspbian and then modifying it, it would be very helpful.And thank you Aimery

Comment: For an introduction to `iptables` (from the Ubuntu doc, but it also applies to Raspbian): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Comment: I tried the command **sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5560 -j ACCEPT**. But of no luck.The program is still giving error _[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address_ can you please tell me a way so that I can connect my android phone to the IP 192.168.100.100:5560 in perticular.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the new error `Errno 99` and where exactly it is happening (line number, client or server program, etc)?

Comment: The error is coming on line no 9 s.bind((host, port)), server side @Aimery

Comment: Do you still have the error when using `host = '0.0.0.0'`? Have you tried connecting to the Pi (to another service, eg ssh) from the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download a software named [Advanced IP Scanner](https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/).

Connect all the devices to the same network i.e Access point.

On the raspberry pi open terminal and type ifconfig get the ipv4 not the 0.0.0.0 or the 127.0.0.1 the other one.

For example if the ip is showing 192.168.100.144 then input 192.168.100.1-255 in Advanced IP scanner in windows start the scan and find the ips that has your raspberry pi's name written in it. Now input these ips in the tcp client and connect.